# Constructors taking initializer lists

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

I get the idea behind uniform initialization with curly braces. But why is that using this syntax on types that have a constructor that takes an initializer list, calls that specific constructor, even though the arguments are only wrapped in a single pair of curly braces, i.e.

```
int main(int argc, const char ** argv)
{
    vector<int> vs0{3};

    for(int v : vs0)
    {
        cout << v << ' ';
    }

    cout << '\n';

    vector<int> vs1(3);

    for(int v : vs1)
    {
        cout << v << ' ';
    }
}

/*
    Output
    3
    0 0 0
*/
```

Why does vs0 get constructed with the initializer list constructor? Shouldn't it be

```
vector<int> v2{{3}};
```

for that? It's kind of confusing, especially if you're not aware that a class has a constructor that takes an initializer list.

Comment: Yeah, it is confusing, which is why it is infamously called Unicorn Initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking for motivation, as opposed to where in the standard it says this must be done. For that you can look at the [original proposal N1919 for intializer lists](https://www.stroustrup.com/N1919-initializer_lists.pdf) by Bjarne Stroustrup, the C++ language creator.

He lists four ways to intialise an object:

```
X t1 = v; // “copy initialization” possibly copy construction
X t2(v); // direct initialization
X t3 = { v }; // initialize using initializer list
X t4 = X(v); // make an X from v and copy it to t4
```

Note that he's not talking about C++11, or a proposed version where initializer lists were introduced. This is back in C++98. That brace initialiser syntax already worked, but *only for C-style structs* i.e. with no user-defined constructor. This is a holdover from C, which has always allowed initialising structs (and arrays) this way, and it will always do the same thing: initialise element-by-element.

The whole point of the proposal is to allow initialisation for proper C++ objects like `std::vector<int>` in the same way as those C-style structs and arrays: C++ is meant to allow user-defined classes to look like built-in types (hence e.g. operator overloading) and here's one place it didn't. To turn your question around, the thing that is odd is not that `std::vector<int>{3}` calls the initialiser list constructor, the thing that is odd is that `std::vector<std::string>{3}` calls the non-initialiser list constructor. Why does it *ever* call a non-initialiser list constructor? That's not really what brace initialisation was originally for. The answer to that is to allow fix-length containers with hand-written constructors, like this:

```
class Vector3D {
public:
    Vector3D(double x, double y, double z) { /*...*/ }
    // ...
};
Vector3D v = {1, 2, 3}; // Ought to call non-initialiser list constructor
```

That is why constructors taking `std::initializer_list` are preferred (if available) when using brace initialisation. For those knowing the background, the use of brace initialisers for everything, as has become the fashion, seems really perverse: `Foo f{7}` looks like `f` will directly contain the number `7` and nothing else after construction completes, not that it does something arbitrary like construct something 7 elements long.

Answer (score 2):

If the class has a constructor taking `std::initializer_list`, then it'll be preferred when being passed a *braced-init-list* in [list initliazation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

> - Otherwise, the constructors of `T` are considered, in two phases:
>
>   - All constructors that take [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) as the only argument, or as the first argument if the remaining arguments have
>       default values, are examined, and matched by [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution)
>       against a single argument of type [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)
>   - If the previous stage does not produce a match, all constructors of `T` participate in [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Implicit_conversion_sequence_in_list-initialization) against the set of arguments that
>       consists of the elements of the braced-init-list, with the restriction
>       that only non-narrowing conversions are allowed. If this stage
>       produces an explicit constructor as the best match for a
>       copy-list-initialization, compilation fails (note, in simple
>       copy-initialization, explicit constructors are not considered at all).

`{3}` is a braced-init-list, then the `vector` will be initialized as containing 1 element with value `3`. The behavior is consistent with passing `{1, 2}`, `{1, 2, 3}` and so on.